# Creating a numpy array from dictionary with keys containing index tuples

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have two dictionaries as follows

```
o = {0: -0.0, 1: -0.0, 2: -0.0, 3: -0.0, 4: -0.0, 5: -0.0, 6: -0.0, 7: -0.0, 8: -0.0, 9: -0.0}
```

and

```
X = {(0, 0): 1.0, (0, 1): 0.0, (0, 2): 0.0, (1, 0): 0.0, (1, 1): 1.0, (1, 2): 0.0, (2, 0): 1.0, (2, 1): 0.0, (2, 2): 0.0}
```

I want to create numpy arrays such that the key value in the dictionary corresponds to the array index and value correspond to the value.

For example, in case of the second dictionary, my output should be

```
X = np.array([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
X = {(0, 0): 1.0, (0, 1): 0.0, (0, 2): 0.0, (1, 0): 0.0, (1, 1): 1.0, (1, 2): 0.0, (2, 0): 1.0, (2, 1): 0.0, (2, 2): 0.0}

result = np.zeros((3,3))
for key, val in X.items():

    result[key[0]][key[1]] = val

print (result)
```

output:

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I wrote a small script for you, help you solve with all dictionary

```
import numpy as np
def dict2arr(dictionary):
    # take all keys in dict
    l = list(dictionary.keys())
    # if result is 1D tensor
    if type(l[0])== int:
        result = np.zeros((len(dictionary)))
    # if result is nD tensor with n > 1
    else:
        # take the maximum shape, then plus 1 to generate correct shape
        shape = [i+1 for i in max(l)]
        result = np.zeros(shape)
    # just let the key is index and value is value of result
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        result[k]=v
    return result
```

Result with X:

`array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])`

Result with o:

`array([-0., -0., -0., -0., -0., -0., -0., -0., -0., -0.])`

Hope this is right solution!